# Why does RandomFunction return variable number of data points?

Tags: random, stochastic-calculus

I am using the following code snippet to generate Compound Poisson process random numbers:

```
P = CompoundPoissonProcess[1, NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
dataP = RandomFunction[P, {1, 10}]
```

I am using Mathematica 10 and on different runs of the code I get variously 10 points or 9 points or 13 points...

Is this normal?

How can I force Mathematica to get $n$ data points...

Comment: You get as many points as necessary to cover time values from 1 to 10. In the case of Poisson processes, number of events per unit of time varies.

Answer (score 3):

Use an explicit time step in `RandomFunction` to get 10 points in resulting `TemporalData`:

```
P = CompoundPoissonProcess[1, NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
dataP = RandomFunction[P, {1, 10, 1}]
```